# AgGrid/Angular 5: constructor not instantiating service class in init() function for Cell Rendering in AgGrid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am having an issue with the non-enterprise version of *AgGrid* and *Angular 5*.

**The Angular apps webpage component loads and AgGrid loads using the following bit of code - this works fine...**

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.agGridOptions = {
      onGridReady: (grid) => this.onGridReady(grid),
      onCellValueChanged: (grid) => this.updateRowItem(grid),
      enableSorting: false,
      enableFilter: false,
      enableColResize: true,
      unSortIcon: true,
      components : {
        'valueRendererComponent'          : ValueRendererComponent,
        'StartDateRendererComponent' : StartDateRendererComponent,
        'EndDateRendererComponent'   : EndDateRendererComponent
      }
    };
  }
```

This loads the grid fine and dandy. The issue is when I edit a row cells value and the cells rendering component runs some logic and updates.

**Below are the grids column definitions for better understanding of the way cells are being rendered via external component...**

```
const columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Val',
        field: 'Value',
        width: 500,
        editable: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Start Date',
        field: 'StartDate',
        width: 500,
        cellRenderer: 'StartDateRendererComponent',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        headerName: 'End Date',
        field: 'EndDate',
        width: 500,
        cellRenderer : 'EndDateRendererComponent',
        editable: true
      }
    ];
```

This issue I am experiencing is with the `EndDateRendererComponent` (example below) to be rendered via the `cellRenderer` column definition parameter and not being able to properly inject the `ConfigStateService` (example below) into said component via the Angular 5 `constructor() {}` method that makes all values in the `ConfigStateService` available within AgGrid's `init()` function.

**Here is the `EffectiveEndDateRendererComponent` Component...**

```
import { ConfigStateService } from './../fakepath';

export class EndDateRendererComponent {
  public ConfigStateService: ConfigStateService;
  public eGui: any;

  constructor(
      public configStateService: ConfigStateService,
    ) {
    // this.configStateService = ConfigStateService.prototype;
  }

  public getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
  }

  public init(params) {
    console.log(this.configStateService);

    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = params['data']['effectiveEndDate'];
    this.eGui.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
}
```

**Here is the `ConfigStateService`...**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import includes from 'lodash-es/includes';
import difference from 'lodash-es/difference';
import intersection from 'lodash-es/intersection';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigStateService {
  public _addNewSaveButtonsStatus = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  public testing() {
    console.log(this._addNewSaveButtonsStatus)
  }
}
```

As seen above, when I try to `console.log(this.configStateService)` in the `init()` function of the `EndDateRendererComponent`, I am getting undefined. But If I console.log(ConfigStateService) outside of the component it is clearly being imported fine. Additionally, if I import the `configStateService` outside in a different component that has nothing to do with AgGrid, the service instantiates and works fine, underlining the likely realtiy that the problem is with the `init()` built in function for AgGrid and how it interacts with service injection.

***How can I access all the values in the ConfigServiceState within the `init()` function in my `EndDateRendererComponent`?***